# How would I split a list into multiple specific lists

Tags: python

Hey this is my first post so I apologize if its poorly done,

I'm trying to split this list in a text file:

```
2 pig oink
3 duck quack
4 horse neigh
5 lamb baa
6 chickens cluck
7 dog woof
8 cat meow
9 cow moo
```

into 3 separate lists for [number], [animal], [sound]

So far I have this:

```
 import os
 import linecache
    
 def main():            
     with open('animals.txt') as animal_file:
         contents = animal_file.read()
         x = contents.split()
         print(x)
 main()
```

which yields:

```
['2', 'pig', 'oink', '3', 'duck', 'quack', '4', 'horse', 'neigh', '5', 'lamb', 'baa', '6', 'chickens', 'cluck', '7', 'dog', 'woof', '8', 'cat', 'meow', '9', 'cow', 'moo']
```

Any and every piece of advice I receive will be greatly appreciated

Comment: use readlines ... and then split each line rather than splitting the whole thing

Answer (score 4):

You can use `split` and `zip`:

```py
with open('animals.txt') as f:
    numbers, animals, sounds = zip(*map(str.split, f))

print(numbers) # ('2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9')
print(animals) # ('pig', 'duck', 'horse', 'lamb', 'chickens', 'dog', 'cat', 'cow')
print(sounds) # ('oink', 'quack', 'neigh', 'baa', 'cluck', 'woof', 'meow', 'moo')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import csv

with open('file.txt') as f:
    number, animal, sound = zip(*csv.reader(f, delimiter=' '))

print(number)
print(animal)
print(sound)
```

output:

```
('2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9')
('pig', 'duck', 'horse', 'lamb', 'chickens', 'dog', 'cat', 'cow')
('oink', 'quack', 'neigh', 'baa', 'cluck', 'woof', 'meow', 'moo')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
with open("file.txt", "r") as file:
    lines = list(zip(*map(lambda x: x.split(), file.read().splitlines())))
    print(lines)
    # [('2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'), ('pig', 'duck', 'horse', 'lamb', 'chickens', 'dog', 'cat', 'cow'), ('oink', 'quack', 'neigh', 'baa', 'cluck', 'woof', 'meow', 'moo')]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few way's you could approach this problem:

1. Split on each new line with the `str.splitlines()` then separate each one into the correct list.
2. Iterate through the list you have with a loop and place each item into the correct list by counting three at a time
3. You could write some conditionals to determine if something is a number/animal/sound (Not recommended)

If all else fails you can copy and paste the answer above